# The story may not be interesting; the story may be not interesting

Tags: negation

> The story may **not** be interesting.
>   The story may be **not** interesting.

For I’m not sure if ‘*not*’ can be placed both before and after ‘*be*,’ I looked up the COCA. It seems that both are possible. Are both grammatically acceptable? If they are, isn’t there semantic difference between the two?

Comment: I personally find the latter sentence clear but unidiomatic, if only because the concept of "not interesting" is typically expressed with the single word "uninteresting".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grammatically speaking, the place of 'not' is between may and be.  The correct and natural sentence is "The story may not be interesting.